# Sliding View From the Left

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4

I am trying to build a app that will have a view hidden unless you pull it from right. For example the Dolphin web browser for iOS has the ability to pull from the right and it will bring up your favorites and some other options. Does anyone know of a way to implement that into a application? Is there some code or tutorials floating around?

Heres the link to the Dolphin iOS App: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dolphin-browser-hd/id460812023?mt=8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create two views. ViewA & ViewB
2. ViewA is the view that loads.
3. Add ViewB to ViewA with ViewB being off the screen so the user cannot see it.
4. in ViewDidLoad of ViewA add a UISwipeGestureRecognizer so you can be notified of a swipe gesture.
5. If swipe happens move ViewB into view with a UITransition.

in viewDidLoad to capture swipe gesture

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeDetected)];
    [viewA addGestureRecognizer:swipe];
    [swipe release];

-(void)swipeDetected {
     //transition viewB into view of user
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
     [UIView setAnimationDelay:0];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
     CGRect rect5 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
     viewB.frame = rect5;       
     [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: could you be more precise on how to do this? It would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is called a `UIGestureRecognizer`, particularly a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with direction `UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft`.

You can find the related [Apple reference here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISwipeGestureRecognizer). Gesture recognizers are very straight forward if you are using a apple one like this. If you need help on specifics, post and I can type up a quick example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Boctor wrote a very good tutorial on implementing a swipe on a UITableViewCell (like twitter/tweetie, and the app you've described) [here](http://idevrecipes.com/2011/04/14/how-does-the-twitter-iphone-app-implement-side-swiping-on-a-table/).